# Getting other html elements from svg's external JS script

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have an svg image which I add in my `.html` document using `<object>` tags this:

```
<object data="./svg/bookmark.svg" type="image/svg+xml" id="bookmark"></object>
```

I can then position the svg in `.css` file like this:

```
#bookmark{
            position: absolute;
            top: 0rem;
            left: calc(30rem - 0.1rem);
            z-index: 10;
            width: 1.25rem;
            height: auto;
}
```

So styling is working.

This svg should reveal a menu which slides from the left when svg is pressed. I tried implementing JS like this:

1. **I modified an svg:**

   - I enabled sourcing to external JS by adding this attribute inside the `<svg>` tag.:

     ```
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     ```
   - I inserted a link to the external JS after the `<svg>` tag:

     ```
     <script xlink:href="../js/bookmark.js" />
     ```
   - I added an `onclick` insid the `<path>` tag:

     ```
     onclick="bookmark_click()"
     ```
2. **I created an external JS file** `../js/bookmark.js` with the folowing content:

   ```
   function bookmark_click(){
        console.log("Bookmark clicked.");

        let x = document.getElementById("menu");
        console.log(x);
   }
   ```

And I got this output in the browser's console:

[image]

It looks like external JS script can execute simple JS commands, but fails to see other elements in my webpage - we can see that `x` is returned as `null`. What am I doing wrong? I don't want to embed svg directly in my `.html` document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the element with id="menu" is in the SVG's parent HTML document then you can use parent to get it i.e.

```
let x = parent.document.getElementById("menu")
```